# Tengo un problema con una estructura y bucle for, ¿Alguien sabe por que puede ser?

Tags: bucle-for, struct, estructuras

Hola voy empezando en programación, pero no puedo hacer que funcione este código, alguien sabe porque puede ser? es una estructura con un bucle for para que despliegue los datos, me aparece este error "expected expression before ‘{’ token" en todas las líneas de la información de las materias

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct datosMaterias{
    char *nombreMateria;
    char *carrera;
    int horasSemana; 
    int horasLaboratorio;   
};

void materias(){
    struct datosMaterias materia[9];
    materia[0] = {"Ingles","Desarrollo xd",20,10};
    materia[1] = {"Sistemas","Desarrollo de software",10,15};
    materia[2] = {"Estadistica","Desarrollo de software",10,5};
    materia[3] = {"Fundamentos de programacion","Desarrollo de software",10,5};
    materia[4] = {"Base de datos","Desarrollo de software",10,1};
    materia[5] = {"Fisica","Desarrollo de software",15,5};
    materia[6] = {"Quimica","Desarrollo de software",10,8};
    materia[7] = {"Calculo diferencial","Desarrollo de software",5,7};
    materia[8] = {"Matematicas","Desarrollo de software",9,9};
    
    system("cls");
    int i=0;
    
    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
        printf("Nombre: %s \n Carrera: %s \n Numero de horas por semana: %i \n Horas de laboratorio: %i \n",materia[i].nombreMateria,materia[i].carrera,materia[i].horasSemana,materia[i].horasLaboratorio);
        printf("____\n");
    }
    system("pause");

}

int main(){
    materias();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es simple, en la línea 10, cuando inicializas el primer elemento del array de estructuras, lo haces usando llaves, sin embargo este tipo de inicialización solo está permitida en la declaración de la variable, por ello el compilador te indica error; si deseas inicializar tu variable de este modo, debes hacerlo en la declaración, como se muestra a continuación.

```
struct datosMaterias materia[9] = {
{"Ingles","Desarrollo xd",20,10},
{"Sistemas","Desarrollo de software",10,15},
{"Estadistica","Desarrollo de software",10,5},
{"Fundamentos de programacion","Desarrollo de software",10,5},
{"Base de datos","Desarrollo de software",10,1},
{"Fisica","Desarrollo de software",15,5},
{"Quimica","Desarrollo de software",10,8},
{"Calculo diferencial","Desarrollo de software",5,7},
{"Matematicas","Desarrollo de software",9,9}};
```

Eso debería resolver tu problema. Por otro lado, si no quieres/puedes inicializar tu array de esta manera, lo que puedes hacer, es inicializar elemento por elemento, miembro por miembro.